# is sendmail aliases sending the email received as a parameter when redirecting to program?

Tags: email, java, sendmail

good afternoon,

I am learning sendmail and had a doubt about how aliases work.

If I have the entry below in my /etc/aliases

> import@domain.com: "| java -jar importFromEmail.jar import@domain.com"

QUESTION: Is sendmail sending the email received and "import@domain.com" as parameters or only import@domain.com?

thank you very much

Comment: Do you use non standard `sendmail` configuration?  Standard `sendmail ` configuration supports "domain less" aliases (local domain is stripped before alias lookup)

Answer (score 1):

Sendmail is probably (I use postfix, but its similar, and this is standard unix syntax) executing the command  java -jar with the parameters importFromEmail.jar import@domain.com and piping the email to stdin to the program.

We know this because of the "|" symbol which means direct output to input of the next command.

Comment: "piping the email to stdin to the program" what would happen with the headers and the email attachments?

Comment: They are part of the email, so they wpuld be piped in as well.